# Can I highlight a cell based on the result of a vlookup with an if statement?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Can I highlight a cell based on the result of a vlookup with an if statement?

ie =if(vlookup(a1,B:C,1,0)=0,"No","Yes") where then the cell can be hightlight Red if "No" and Green if "Yes"

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional formatting to do this. Hit the "Conditional Formatting" button, click "New Rule". Choose "Use a formula to determine which cells to format". In the box below that selection area stick in a formula that will return a TRUE or a FALSE, like `vlookup(a1,B:C,1,0)=0` IF this statement is true, then the conditional formatting will be applied, if it is false, then it won't be.

For more information on Conditional Formatting: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/quick-start-apply-conditional-formatting-HA010370614.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I perhaps over simplified my question, the "Yes" element will be a numerical value in my situation the latest price of a particular month, the "No" where no price is available in that particular month will be a formula which I know. So I want to show one colour is a new price for that month and a different colour to represent the price is from a previous month

Comment: I have edited my answer to better suit your question.